# slimScroll.js is not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, slimscroll

i am working on  slimScroll.js  i applied on one my div such as

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/slimScroll.js"></script>

 $(".hlDiv").slimScroll({
     height : '295px',
     width : '100%',
     });
```

Its working on CHROME and OPERA BROWSER but its not working on Mozilla Firefox  version 16.0.1.

also included necessary jquery-ui file. but still stuck.

gone through various site but doesn't find any answer.

Any clue or reference will help me lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look into the console?

Comment: if .slimScroll not a function post you jQuery version

Comment: This might be the answer to your pb: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886281/event-wheeldelta-returns-undefined

Answer (score 1):

remove the `,` in the line:

```
width : '100%',
```

your version of firefox is a little strict in syntax.