# my javascript code looks weird in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Can anyone help me to find out why this page looks fine in FireFox and safari
but in Chrome and IE it looks like it has little annoying jumping frames.

I'm using animate with 0 delay to move the < sections > up or down depending on the scroll, so it looks like one sections eats up the previous one is kind of parallax but, not only the background but the entire section.

http://bksn.mx/tequilaarsenal/public/index/arsenal

My javascript code comments are in Spanish but I will gladly translate any if needed.

Here is a brief example of the JavaScript code that does this

```
tempScrollTop=0;
$(window).scroll(function(e) {

    windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 

    scrollDiff = tempScrollTop-windowTop;

    $("#sectionToMove").parallaxMio(p0,scrollDiff);
    tempScrollTop = windowTop;

});


$.fn.parallaxMio = function(pInicial,scrollDiff){
    if (scrollDiff < 0 ){
        //scroll down
        $(this).stop().animate({ top: '+='+scrollDiff }, 0);
    else if (scrollDiff > 0){
        //scroll up
        $(this).stop().animate({ top: '+='+scrollDiff }, 0);

    }

};
```

Comment: @JonathandeM. It's Javascript - all the code is online...

Comment: I do not spot any difference.

Comment: neither do I. Looks like that might not be the problem :/

Comment: Try using small images as your background; could be the images are too big for the browser to be animated smoothly. Just give it a try.

Comment: @supertonsky ok i ll give it a try

Comment: @helly0d do you see the anoying jumping on both browsers or it seems right for you in both?

Comment: The problem is that FF implements a delta on the event and gives you a smoothness level. You would have to implement that yourself for the rest of the browsers especially if the user has a wheel with stepper.

Comment: @GaddielSadocPeralta It seemed ok because i have a special wheel ( i have a sqeuaky wheel ... was that me? ) where i can set it on stepper mode or smooth mode. In stepper mode it goes 40 pixels per step ( the delta i told you about ) in smooth mode it just scrolls based on the force applied on the wheel to spin. In smooth mode it went smooth, but in stepper mode i've seen your problem, and i am trying to find an old piece of code which solved the problem for me a long time ago.

Comment: @helly0d that explains, I really hope you find that code ^^

Comment: Try this chrome://chrome/settings/content and tick on "Do not show any images". Tried on my chrome and the jerky motion went smooth when trying to click on one of the menu that scrolls the screen down.

Comment: Also, try inspecting the divs you created by executing this on your chrome's console: `$("div").css("border","1px solid red")`. Then play with it.

Comment: @supertonsky lol funny option but the anoying jumps are still there for me :(

Comment: When scrolling down some divs are trying to maintain their position until you reached a certain point and that i think is causing the flickers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(evt) {
    var e = window.event || evt
    var scrollDiff = e.detail?e.detail*(-120):e.wheelDelta;
    $("#sectionToMove").parallaxMio(p0,scrollDiff);
});
```

`e.wheelDelta` exists in FF while `e.detail` is in the rest and tells you the direction and the amount of scrolling being made. Also `e.wheelDelta` is most of the time `e.detail * (-120)`.

P.S. As an advice try to declare your private variables ( `scrollDiff` for example ), because you will "pollute" your global space and will wonder at one moment "why does this variable exist in window", and also "why do my functions which use the same variable names do not work properly".

EDIT:

See also this link: http://phrogz.net/js/wheeldelta.html

Comment: this: 
   console.log(e.details?e.details*(-120):e.wheelDelta);
displays undefined, am I missing somethig?

Comment: That means jQuery does not pass the e argument for which you will have to do something like this `var e = window.event || e`. I hate jQuery by the way. Please people learn some real JavaScript before trying any library.

Comment: not yet :( I just uploaded the changes in js including the console.log

Comment: @GaddielSadocPeralta You should change on line 61 the argument of that function to evt.

Comment: and sorry my bad is `e.detail` not `details`

Comment: Ok... now i am MAD. jQuery just seems to wrap that event into too much trouble. Give me 10 - 15 minutes to figure out what did JavaScript wrong to deserve jQuery.

Comment: Ok... after one long search and 2 cigars i have no clue where to find the original event. jQuery just won't give it to you, and people say that jQuery is good. I just give up, the only way to find the delta in jQuery is the way you do it, and it seems it doesn't do any good. Try with smaller images as others suggested, but i know i've worked with this code and it worked like magic without any other libraries. Have fun i will have my answer deleted after you have an accepted answer.

Comment: dude thanks a lot for all your help! I m sure your clues will gide me to the awnser and then I hope you wont need to remove your awnser since it will be the correct one :)

Comment: finnaly worked, i got the event with a non jquery bind based in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886281/event-wheeldelta-returns-undefined
but the logic is all yours, thx a lot @helly0d