# Mouse Wheel event always returns less than 0 (down) in firefox? [JQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

I'm using JQuery to detect if the mousewheel has scrolled up or down, and it works in all browsers except firefox, which always seems to think it's scrolling down.  Any help is appreciated!

```
$('html,body').bind('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e){
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
        alert('scrolling up !');
    }
    else {
        alert('scrolling down !');
    }
});
```

JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Qvs2r/1/

Comment: `alert(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta)` returns "undefined"

Comment: Here's your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886281/event-wheeldelta-returns-undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this before you condition :

```
var theEvent = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || e.originalEvent.detail*-1
```

And you condition

```
if ( theEvent /120 > 0)
```

`*-1` is there because somehow, firefox reverse the scrolling value.

Comment: Why do you divide the value before comparing it to zero?

Comment: @YMMD It is in the OP code.But yeah, it is useless in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel" //FF doesn't recognize mousewheel as of FF3.x

if (document.attachEvent) //if IE (and Opera depending on user setting)
    document.attachEvent("on"+mousewheelevt, function(e){alert('Mouse wheel movement detected!')})
else if (document.addEventListener) //WC3 browsers
    document.addEventListener(mousewheelevt, function(e){alert('Mouse wheel movement detected!')}, false)
```

EDIT: Nevermind, I just noticced you had that. I think the problem is in the first IF statement. You should debug that in Firebug and see what values e holds.