# css zoom will decrement but not increment properly

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using the following function to zoom a div.  It works fairly well when you zoom out (scroll down), but when you zoom in (scroll up) the currentZoom jumps to 10 instead of 1.1.  From that point you can zoom out but you cannot zoom in again (I'm assuming CSS zoom is limited).

What am I missing?

```
$('#workArea').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentZoom = $(this).css('zoom');
    alert(currentZoom);
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
        currentZoom += .1;
        $(this).animate({ 'zoom': currentZoom }, 400);
    } else {
        currentZoom -= .1;
        $(this).animate({ 'zoom': currentZoom }, 400);
    }
});
```

Credit to [event.wheelDelta returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886281/event-wheeldelta-returns-undefined) for the mousewheel code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All CSS properties are returned as strings. This means that `currentZoom += .1` will result in `10.1`. I would guess that you are correct, and that CSS zoom is limited to a fixed range. Zooming in should work again when you return to a zoom level of 1.

To fix the problem, try `currentZoom = parseFloat($(this).css("zoom"));` or
`currentZoom = +$(this).css("zoom")`

Comment: JavaScript. Impossible to love but impossible to hate. `+"Upvote"`

Comment: @Bojangles MySQL suffers a similar problem, returning even `INT` fields as strings - makes it a little difficult to use when passing data from MySQL to JavaScript via JSON ;)