# Mousewheel 3.1.3 (Brandon Aaron) is not working after upgrading jQuery version of 1.10

Tags: jquery, mousewheel

I've upgraded the jQuery version of 1.10 and mousewheel 3.1.3 to my project but mousewheel widget is not working any more.

The mousewheel was working fine before I upgraded to the jQuery 1.10.

What do I need to do to get this working?

I am using jQuery 1.10.2, jQuery UI 1.10.3, mousewheel 3.1.3 by Brandon Aaron

Comment: So what do you want us to do? rewrite the widget/plugin for you? ask the author!

Comment: I just want it running as it should. It was working with jQuery 1.5, jQuery UI 1.8, and mousewheel 3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

The mousewheel plugin works with jQuery 1.10.2.
http://brandonaaron.github.io/jquery-mousewheel/test/index.html?v=1.10.2

Perhaps there is something else that is causing an error and preventing the rest of your scripts from running properly.

Comment: I have figured out the problem that event.wheelDelta returns undefined. Now it is available through the originalEvent property of the jQuery event. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886281/event-wheeldelta-returns-undefined. Thanks Brandon