# Detect number of times mousewheel is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm trying to achieve an effect like the one [here](http://www.apple.com/iphone-5s/). I want to perform an action each time the scroll wheel is scrolled, regardless of how much the user tries to scroll. How would I count the number of times the user tries to scroll? I've been playing around with `$(window).on('scroll'...`. Thanks

Comment: not sure, but to me it looks like theyre just hiding the scrollbar, then when your $(window).on('scroll', ...) fires, you could determine whether youre scrolling up or down by using $(window).scrollTop()? and animate your <div> to show.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something that counts like this:

```
(function() {
    var scroll = 0;
    $(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
        scroll++;
        console.log(event);
    });

    $('#click').on('click', function() {
        alert(scroll);
    });
})();

<button id="click">Show me</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eHEmr/

(you can obviously put your own code instead of `scroll++;`)

Comment: I've tried something like this, but I guess what I need is a way to determine if the scrolling has stopped for a moment, and then increment by 1. This way I can tell how many times the user has tried to scroll, not the distance.

Comment: You can get distances from the event itself.

Comment: I don't this property is available in IE10 or any other modern browser: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8886331/16959

Answer (score 0):

Turns out what I really needed was to find when the scrolling had stopped. Got the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144560/jquery-scroll-detect-when-user-stops-scrolling).

```
var scrolls = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        pos++;
    }, 50));
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mouse Wheel Counter

```
 let wheelCounter = 0;

    // Function to handle mouse wheel events
    function handleMouseWheel(event) {
      // Detect the direction of the mouse wheel
      const direction = event.deltaY > 0 ? 'down' : 'up';

      // Update the counter based on the direction
      if (direction === 'down') {
        wheelCounter++;
      } else {
        wheelCounter--;
      }

      // Display the current count
      console.log(`Mouse wheel turned ${wheelCounter} times`);
    }

    // Attach the event listener to the document
    document.addEventListener('wheel', handleMouseWheel);
```