# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - Scrolling Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to web development. I am trying to get a page to scroll left if the mousewheel goes up, and scroll right if the mousewheel goes down. Here is my code, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(e){
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0)
    {
        $("*").scrollLeft(300);
    }
    else
    {
        $("*").scrollRight(300);
    }
});
```

I'm not sure why it's breaking, anyone have some insight?

Comment: possible duplicate of [event.wheelDelta returns undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886281/event-wheeldelta-returns-undefined)

Comment: the solution in that issue was to include originalEvent. Sadly enough it is in my code

Comment: What about `DOMMouseScroll`? Have you seen fiddle?

Comment: found that scrollRight isn't a function, so now I'm using scrollLeft(-300) but it still isn't doing any scrolling.

Comment: I've tried DOMMouseScroll, but that doesn't work either. The code is entering the if else statements but not scrolling at all. Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NS3Sj/17/

Comment: Take a look here:http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/JqU2T/8/

Answer (score 2):

It's because that's not the point of the [.scrollLeft()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) function.
When you do:

```
$("*").scrollLeft(300);
```

you are saying: take every element and set THEIR scrollbar to 300 on the left. In your fiddle, no element has a scrollbar, so nothing happens. If you want to use that function for this goal, you need a container div with `overflow-x: scroll`. Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NS3Sj/19/) for a simple (and not perfect) example.

An even simpler solution for you would be to change the scrollLeft() value for the window:

```
$(window).scrollLeft($(window).scrollLeft()+300);
```

as in [this other fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NS3Sj/17/).

Comment: Thank you, I would upvote but I need 15 rep. I actually just realized as I was reading the API I just made assumptions based on the function name.

Comment: No prob. I also just edited the answer and added a much easier solution to your problem, let us know if it works for you.

Comment: That works great! I've also modified it so that there's no if else statement, just this 
$(window).scrollLeft($(window).scrollLeft()+e.originalEvent.wheelDelta);
line