# JQuery mousewheel function does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the code below to hide the divs on any scroll up or down. The problem is that it does not work on IE8. Could you please help?

Thanks.

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(e){
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0){
      $('.previewElements').fadeOut();
     $('.cover').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: Removed all others, same issue.

Comment: Question was marked as a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886281/event-wheeldelta-returns-undefined, but code above is using that.

Comment: By does not work, do you mean that your event handler never gets called? Did you put a break point in there?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you attach to the body instead of the window? Also why are you using `bind` instead of `on`? What happens when you do `console.log(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta)`

Comment: @Emil, are you perchance using the 2.x branch of jQuery? That branch does not support IE8 and lower.

Comment: thanks epascarello, it worked to change windows to body :)

Comment: The issue was solved by changing "window" selector to "Body, Html". Thanks for all answers :)