# Horizontal Scroll to next div using mousewheel

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling, mousewheel

I have a horizontal layout website which is basically working very well, except that for those who don't intuitively see how to navigate it seems to be a tad frustrating. So I've implemented mousewheel scrolling horizontally in order to make for yet another means of navigating through the page.  However, I'd really prefer that the scrolling would go directly to the next div and stop, then to the next, etc.  I came across this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801612/scroll-to-next-divs-on-mousewheel-jquery) on stackoverflow, but I'm really not sure how to adapt what I've got.

Here's the code I currently fire in order to get the horizontal scrolling going:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('html, body, *').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
            this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 20);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Each panel in my page is inside an article tag so I'd like each mouse scroll to advance to the next article (or go back to the previous, as the case may be).

I should add that I'd like to disable the horizontal scroll for mobile devices. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: May you create sample fiddle?

Comment: No need. There is already a demo that I worked from to build my site so I'm working with the same markup: [codrops/Tympanus](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/02/responsive-horizontal-layout/)  And, even though the dev site will go away once the site launches, you can go to it if you like:  [dev site](http://pixiedev.lyricoperala.org)

Comment: I'm sorry, I may have been confusing by saying "No need". What I meant is that there's no need to create a sample fiddle since I can provide you with the exact markup in 2 different locations, including my dev site. Hopefully you can assist?