# Jquery mousewheel event working only on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on `jquery` event where `div` with class `low_price` animates based on which direction we scroll.If we scroll up the div scrolls up and scrolls down when we scroll down.

But this code is not working on laptop mousepad scroll.

This code is only working on chrome not on any other browser.

[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/rx532h6o/) is a fiddle.

Here is the code.

```
 $(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
         $(".low_price").animate({top: '0'}, "fast");
    }
    else {
         $(".low_price").animate({top: '80px'}, "fast");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What about to use:

```
event.originalEvent.detail
```

edited 2: https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/1fud1roa/1/

I took it from here: [event.wheelDelta returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886281/event-wheeldelta-returns-undefined)