# Detecting the deltaY on a surface pro device

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website that I need to detect if the user is scrolling up or down without actually scrolling on the page. I currently have it set up like this:

```
checkScrollDirection = function(event) {
    delta = event.originalEvent.deltaY;

    if ( delta < 0 ) {
        scrollDirection = 'up';
    } else {
        scrollDirection = 'down';
    }
}
```

This works perfect for everything else but apparently Microsoft devices like the surface pro doesn't use the deltaY. Does anyone know what the surface pro uses to detect it's mouse scroll position?
I currently can't get it to detect the wheel, scroll, mousewheel, or DOMMouseScroll event unless there is actual scrolling on the page, which this page doesn't have. Even on pages that do scroll, I can't get it to return a value for the deltaY, which is the value I am using to detecting mouse scroll on the page that doesn't have a window scroll.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [event.wheelDelta returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886281/event-wheeldelta-returns-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

you can store window.scrollY value in variable and then compare it every time scrolling event occurs. You can try this.

```
var lastScrollPosition = 0;
window.onscroll = function() {
    var newScrollPosition = window.scrollY;

    if (newScrollPosition < lastScrollPosition){
        //upward - code here
    }else{
        //downward - code here
    }
    lastScrollPosition = newScrollPosition;
}
```

Comment: This won't work because no actual scrolling occurs. That is the reason I need to detect the direction of the mouse movement instead of the window scroll.

Comment: Do you want to detect mouse movement or scroll movement ?

Comment: Mouse movement. That is what the deltaY is giving me. I can't detect window scroll because there is no window scroll on the page. The issue is that the surface pro doesn't return any value from deltaY so I can't detect which direction the user is trying to scroll.

Comment: Then "event.pageX" and "event.pageY" may be able to solve this issue it will give the axis value and then use these values to detect the direction

Comment: The PageY returns undefined just like the deltaY.